# Haskell : Working with monad classes

Tags: class, haskell, monads

As an assignment I need to work with monads in Haskell and create a gambling game that has one simple rule: toss 6 coins, count the heads, roll a dice and if its result is equal to or greater than the amount of heads counted you win, otherwise you lose. I was given the following 'framework' defining a Gambling Monad:

```
data Coin = H | T
    deriving (Bounded, Eq, Enum, Ord, Show)

data Dice = D1 | D2 | D3 | D4 | D5 | D6
    deriving (Bounded, Eq, Enum, Ord, Show)

data Outcome = Win | Lose
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

class Monad m => MonadGamble m where
    toss :: m Coin
    roll :: m Dice

game :: MonadGamble m => m Outcome
game = undefined
```

However I'm still new to Monads and I have no idea how to work with them. For example: the game definition should implement the game I explained above, but how should I work with this Gambling Monad to, for example, execute one or multiple toss(es)/roll(s) and obtain the resulting value(s) so I can use/work with them?

Also from my understanding a Monad always has 2 default functions on it: return and (>>=), but I don't see how this would apply to the MonadGable monad?

If anyone can help me out on this it's much appreciated!

Best regards,
Skyfe.

Comment: You can write the entire logic of the game without having an implementation for `MonadGamble`, and then later you can write `instance MonadGamble some_existing_monad where ...` to get the actual behavior where it runs.

Comment: Just to be clear: in Haskell, a 'type' is (roughly) a set of values.  A 'class' is (somewhat less roughly) a set of types (not a set of values).  So `MonadGamble` is a set of types each of which has the `>>=` and `return` operations, plus the `MonadGamble` operations `toss` and `roll`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, `MonadGamble` is not technically a monad here, but a typeclass extending a monad so that it has two things associated with it: `toss` and `roll`, each signifying the value of a toss or a roll respectively. In the type signature of `game`, `m` is the monad, and it is an instance of `MonadGamble`, so we automatically have available to us `toss` and `roll`.

You can use Haskell's do notation here. I won't go into too much detail as I don't want to do the entire assignment, but here's how you could write a monad which tests if two coin tosses come up the same:

```
twoFlips :: MonadGamble m => m Bool
twoFlips = do
    coin1 <- toss
    coin2 <- toss
    return (coin1 == coin2)
```

You also might find useful the `replicateM` function from `Control.Monad`, which allows us to repeat a monadic action and return the results in a list:

```
import Control.Monad (replicateM)

tenCoins :: MonadGamble m => m [Coin]
tenCoins = replicateM 10 toss
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured I should use the Haskell's structure using <-, even though I'm not sure what it does besides storing the resulting values to be used by a final function, however I don't get how I should actually acquire the real values of (e.g.) coin1 and coin2? Because these are monads right, but how do I get the real value that lays within them? (e.g. f coin1 = H or T)?

Comment: That is actually exactly what ``<-`` does. It extracts the 'real' value contained in the monad and assigns it a name (this is what we mean when we say we 'bind' a monadic value). We are only allowed to do this in a do block because we are forced to then wrap the value back up in a monad at the end of the block.

Answer (score 4):

You can think of `MonadGamble` as a mini-language, with the four constructs:

```
do
    x <- a
    b
```

which runs the program `a` followed by the program `b` (where, in `b`, the variable `x` refers to the result of `a`),

```
return x
```

which is a simple program that just returns `x`,

```
toss
```

which is a simple program that flips the coin once and returns the result (heads or tails), and

```
roll
```

which is a simple program that rolls the die once and returns the result (one of the six faces `D1`-`D6`).

Note that the `Monad` constructs `do` and `return` are also constructs of the `MonadGamble` language; that's what the `Monad m =>` means in the declaration of `MonadGamble`.

What you need to do is write a program that implements the game described, using the four 'constructs' defined above.  Since you're new to monads, you probably want to write the game just using those four constructs, consider how you could simplify it by writing your own helper functions, then look at the [standard Monad library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html) to see what names it gives for your helper functions (I doubt you'll need anything it doesn't have).

To get you started, here's a program that rolls the die and then flips a coin once or twice, depending on the outcome:

```
-- | Roll the die, then if the result is 1-3 flip the coin once, otherwise twice,
-- returning a list of the results.
roller = do
    d <- roll
    if d `elem` [ D1, D2, D3 ]
        then do
            c <- flip
            return [ c ]
        else do
            c0 <- flip
            c1 <- flip
            return [ c0, c1 ]
```